# Closed Vector Loop Direction

Tags: matlab, vector, direction

I have a non-intersecting, closed vector loop and I want to determine whether its in anticlockwise or clockwise direction.

Here is a trivial example

```
[x y] = [0 0; 1 0; 1 1; 0 1; 0 0]
```

is anticlockwise and

```
[x y] = [0 0; 0 1; 1 1; 1 0; 0 0]
```

is clockwise.

Is there a good way to determine if it is clockwise or counterclockwise?

Edit : More examples

```
[x, y]          OR       [x, y]
 0 ,0                     0, 0
 1 ,0.5                   0, 2
 2 ,0                     2, 2
 2 ,2                     2, 0
 0 ,2                     1, 0.5
 0 ,0                     0, 0
```

Now, the above points are joined in the given order only. I need to detect the left case as anti-clockwise and the right one as clockwise.

Comment: Can you give some more data examples. Are your loops always "centered" at `[0,0]`? Are the moves always discrete integers etc? Are numbers aside from `0` and `1` allowed?

Comment: No. the loop starts from anywhere and can go anywhere. It has only 2 restrictions, i.e., it should be closed and non intersecting.

Comment: Edit your question with some more examples

Comment: Can your loop autointersect?

Comment: No. The loop cannot autointersect

Comment: Get the vectors corresponding to displacements between consecutive points. Then get the argument of these vectors. For a clockwise loop, these arguments will sum up to `-pi`. For an anticlockwise one, they'll sum up to `+pi`

Comment: @Bill Do you mean the absolute angle or the relative angle between 2 consecutive vectors. What I got from your solution is `sum(atan(diff(y)./diff(x)))`. Is that correct?

Comment: Better use `[theta,~]=cart2pol(diff(x),diff(y))`, And then `sum(theta)`

Comment: Am I missing something? `X = [1, 0; 0, 1; -1, 0; 0, -1; 1, 0]; sum(cart2pol(diff(X(:,1)), diff(X(:,2))))` returns 0?

Comment: @BillBokeey This method fails for small number of points (3 or 4). A better check is `issorted(theta(1:end-1))`

Comment: @MatthewGunn yeah that's correct. Consider `issorted(theta(1:end-1))` for the convex hull.

Answer (score 1):

The *most* robust way of doing this for non-intersecting convex *and* concave polygons is to compute the [signed area of the polygon](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SignedAreaOfAPolygon/). If the signed area is positive, it is counter-clockwise, otherwise it is clockwise

```
signedArea = 0.5 * sum(x.*y([2:end 1]) - y.*x([2:end 1]));
isClockwise = signedArea < 0;
```